# null reference error with ui.bootstrap.typeahead

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I added to a working page this angular directive from angular ui

```
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.test" placeholder="prima selezionare il comune"
               typeahead="address for address in vm.updateQuartieri($viewValue)"
               typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control"  />
        <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
```

I'm using the controller as syntax, the updateQuartieri return an array of string and all the controller is working fine. When I start to type in the text box, I receive this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at http://localhost:43638/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:3602:24
```

looking to the source

var getMatchesAsync = function(inputValue) {

```
var locals = {$viewValue: inputValue};
isLoadingSetter(originalScope, true);
$q.when(parserResult.source(originalScope, locals)).then(function(matches) {

  //it might happen that several async queries were in progress if a user were typing fast
  //but we are interested only in responses that correspond to the current view value
  var onCurrentRequest = (inputValue === modelCtrl.$viewValue);
  if (onCurrentRequest && hasFocus) {
    if (matches.length > 0) {
```

looks like the errors occur during the server call, because before I do the call all is fine, and happens before the server call returns data.
   I'm using angular 1.3.
   Any suggestions?
Luca

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm having the exact issue. It was working until I moved the function to a child controller

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I solved, the problem is that the call to the controller in the typeahead is asynchronous, so the method that you're going to call must return a promise, not the actual data.